# asp.net entity data source performance issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

[Simple test page](https://ssctracker.azurewebsites.net/adm/test1) is taking ~4s to load small data set via entity data source. [Clone of page](https://ssctracker.azurewebsites.net/adm/test2) loading same data using SQL data source takes 70ms.

Run on local server accessing Azure DB EF and SQL are even on performance. Ran SQL profiler, and SQL nearly identical and fast (~20ms).

Azure hosted asp.net web app targeting.Net 4.7.2 with EF6. Other pages in project using same data model have similar performance issues. I've used EF6 on similar projects without issue.

```
  <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsLists"></asp:GridView>
  </div>

  <asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsLists" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="name=DatabaseEntities" 
      DefaultContainerName="DatabaseEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
      EntitySetName="Lists" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" Where=""  
      Include="">
  </asp:EntityDataSource>


    <div>
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsLists"></asp:GridView>
    </div>

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="edsLists" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Lists]">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Update:**
Here is output from trace:
[image]

[image]

Here is trace of same page use SQL data source:

[image]

Performance EF6(test1)/SQL(test2):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the Platform is behaving abnormally and there is an additional latency incurred due to App Services Infrastructure. If the issue is happening right now, collect a profiler trace by going to Diagnose and Solve Blade, Diagnostics as a Service and by choosing CLR Profiler to identify the slowness..

**Recommendation**

- Enable or Check Application Insights for your web app.
- Get Memory Dump of Process
- Run Remote Profiler

Also i would suggest you to run the NHibernate profile for entity framework to see any N+1 issues, if it is there fix it before running.

If you have any questions or concerns, please let me know.

To give you a gist, here is the process we follow for troubleshooting it.
Though it is related to dot net core but you can find it similar to asp.net as well in azure web app:

- Go to Diagnose and solve problems blade -- > Diagnostic Tools. If the stack is detected to be “ASP.NET Core”, the tools will be listed as below.  If not, you can select the option on the right.
- Now “Collect .NET Profiler Trace” is listed in ASP.NET Core stack.
- Click “Collect .NET Profiler”. 
  It requires some code level changes in order for the .NET Core applications to emit ETW events.
  The requirements message for collecting ASP.NET Core Profiler Trace is shown as below.
  Make sure the web app meets the requirements.
- There are two data collection modes: Collect and Analyze Data & Collect Data Only.
  “Collect Data Only” will not generate the analyze report.

## - If you choose “Collect Data Only”

Click “Collect Profiler Trace” button to start the collection as you would for a normal .NET application.

- After the data collection finishes, you can click the link to download .zip file (diagsession) and analyze locally via perfview.

Last 5 profiling sessions are listed in the current “Collect .NET Profiler Trace” tab.

- Click “here” to jump to “Diagnostic Tools” tab to see all sessions. From there you can download data and report.
  There is disk space usage information in each session. Based on this information you can delete some sessions to release the disk space.

## - If you choose “Collect and Analyze Data”

You can not only download zip file but also open analyze report.
.NET Core Support is available in Profiler Trace Analyzer.

- .NET Core Support in Profiler Trace Analyzer 
  Slow Requets
  [image]

  “.NET Core Slow Requets” tab in Profiler Trace Report. It shows the top slowest ASP.NET Core requests in this trace.

The Details of each slow request lists Call Stack and Full Request Trace:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Mohit...actually I had performed traces on both the app and sql, but still can't understand the cause. I will paste the call stack into my post...perhaps you can spot the issue.